# Voiced or voiceless cluster in "Brexit?"

Tags: pronunciation, spelling-pronunciations

I was watching American national news coverage of the "Brexit" poll, and it seemed to me that none of the news anchors nor commentators used a voiced consonant cluster in their pronunciation of the word. That is they all pronounced it /bɹɛ**ks**ɪt/ and not /bɹɛ**gz**ɪt/. Upon discussing the poll with two American friends, I realized that they too use the voiceless pronunciation. The older of the two even defended his rendering of the word, saying, "It's spelled with an ex."

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exit), the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/exit), and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exit) list the voiced version of "exit" first, so I would assume it's the more popular or traditional one. Although the spelling and latin origin would lead me to believe the voiceless pronunciation is conventional, "exotic" and "exhaust" both have those qualities too and only have the option of a voiced cluster.

What is the frequency of the voiceless consonant cluster, /ks/, versus the voiced one, /gz/, in "exit?"

Comment: Won't anyone pronounce this the same way they pronounce "exit"?  It has the same choice of voiced or voiceless.

Comment: @GEdgar Dictionary references to "exit" clarified.

Comment: I don't always use the word "brexit".  But when I do, I pronounce it: dos equis.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason, I definitely would not use /gz/ in "Brexit." I can use it in "exit," but I try to avoid it because /ks/ seems more regular (the usual "rule" is that "x" between vowels is /ks/ after stressed syllables, and /gz/ before stressed syllables). I don't think any native speakers have /ks/ in "exotic" or "exhaust," but there are a number of possible exceptions to the "rule" that can be pronounced with unexpected /gz/, such as *exit* and *exile.* However, I can't think of any exceptions where /ks/ is not also an option.

Comment: Oh, apparently there are some exceptions to the voicing of "x" before a stressed syllable, such as: *taxonomy, taxation, vexation.* Taken from here: https://toshuo.com/2005/when-is-x-pronounced-as-gz/ I wonder if it's because the first vowels are generally not reduced, and have some level of stress.

Comment: I suspect that most people, like myself, simply tack a "br" sound on the front of "exit", since the term is a contraction of "British exit".  Close as I understand the IPA (I don't), this produces /bɹɛksɪt/.  Yes, there are those who put an egg in "exit", and I presume they would pronounce "Brexit" differently as a result.  Thankfully, I don't have to listen to them very much.

Comment: I definitely say egzit, but brecksit.  Hypercorrection of funny new word? Or are we all just listening to Katty Kay?

Comment: The word is less than a year old, and it's been common in the US only for a couple months. Plus we tend not to talk about it here; we hear it on the radio and TV or read about it. It's been Somebody Else's Problem. So you're not gonna find any uniformity. I find myself saying it either way, same as I say _exit_ (i.e, I vary from instance to instance in how I say it, just like I do with _with_). So the responses here pretty much sum it up: Do it any way you like, because native speakers do it that way.

Comment: Is this the actual question in your post: "*What is the frequency of the voiceless consonant cluster, /ks/, versus the voiced one, /gz/, in 'exit?'*"? Is that it? If so, why all the stuff about "*brexit*"? Or is your question "*Voiced or voiceless cluster in 'Brexit?'*"? What exactly is your question?

Comment: What @John said. I think the difference is too trivial for most people to even *know* which they use without thinking or trying it out, and lots of us oscillate meaninglessly anyway, and don't particularly notice which versions others use either. It has no significance.

Comment: I don't doubt that, if there were an actual survey of how people pronounce _exit_ or _with_ in unmonitored speech (and in other contexts), there would be all kinds of correlations with socioeconomic class, educational level, ethnic/racial background, etc, etc, etc. There always are in good sociolinguistic studies. But it's an area of variation, i.e, there is no single rule, but rather a whole lot of contradictory rules being followed simultaneously.

Comment: @John Lawler and FumbleFingers, would one of you author an answer? I believe both of your comments are enough to satisfy my question.

Comment: It's pronounced like you would when it gets too cold to stay: *Br...+"ex"+it*. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ex#nav2

Comment: One other point is that two different people may *hear* the identical sounds differently.  Some people are quite sensitive (probably over-sensitive) to subtle shifts in pronunciation, while other people tend to not even notice the difference.

Comment: I would have said that I pronounced 'exit' with a 'ks', but tried it out and I don't, I put an egg in it. My 'Brexit' is eggless however, and I think this may me because 'Breg' doesn't sound like the way a proper British-english word would begin, but 'Brek' does. I'll have eggs in my breakfast, but not in my Brexit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editor [Stan Carey ran a poll](https://twitter.com/StanCarey/status/748195932672516100) on this last week:

> 'Brexit' pronunciation poll: 75% say the 'x' like -ks-, 23% like -gz-, 2% other (n=534). Lots of interesting [replies](https://twitter.com/StanCarey/status/747831383444316160)